# Use value of @Input to other variable without onInit in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to use `@Input` value to initialize other variable in angular 4

```
export class test {
  @Input() id: string;

  condition: boolean = (this.id == 'myid') //Getting this.id as undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `id` variable directly like `id` instead of `this.id` inside a class itself. You have to access variable using `this` only when variable appeared inside `function`. But eventually this wouldn't help you, since `id` value will always be `undefined`.

Ideally you should use this value inside `ngOnInit` hook which gets fired when component gets initialized and you will see the value passed from the consumer component.

```
export class test {
  @Input() id: string;
  condition: boolean;

  ngOnInit(){
     this.condition = (this.id == 'myid')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `@Input` is first available at `ngOnInit`. So you can't access it before `ngOnInit` call.